# Can't run mvn command on windows from unpacked source archive

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

My laptop got stolen so I had to redownload Java and Maven and I can't seem to get Maven up and running, even though I had no problems last time. I have the following locations:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4
```

In my environment settings, I added the following system variables:

```
M2_HOME - C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
```

I updated my `Path` system variable so that the following would be at the beginning:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;
```

All this I got from the [Maven installation instructions](http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation). However, when I open a new command prompt and check the version, I get the following message:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

**UPDATE**

When I installed Java, I noticed `java -version` automatically started working without me having to do anything. Might there be a Java conflict somewhere?

Comment: It seems to me that in order for this to work, you should add `%M2_HOME%\bin` to your path (instead of `%M2`).

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Since your answer, I have updated the question text. It doesn't work that way either.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg In the command prompt? A similar message to the maven. Is not recognized, etc.

Comment: How did you updated `PATH`? Follow this [instructions](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: @janisz I updated the `Path` variable like the way those instructions do.

Comment: Sorry - env is unix? Is it set in windows to list all env variables like path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path variable should have `%M2_HOME%\bin` instead of `%M2%\bin`

Comment: Does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %M2_HOME%` show correct folders ? Is M2_HOME set as system property (I faced similar issue when I placed it in user properties)

Comment: Ok. Before we troubleshoot in a different way.. can you restart your machine and check again ?

Comment: Shut down and started back up. Same thing :(

Comment: Fine. Go to the maven's bin folder and then try the command. Assuming that it works, try it using relative path/absolute path from other directories. Once they work.. try adding `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin` directly to path variable

Comment: PFT. There was no bin directory. I accidentally downloaded the Maven source zip instead of the binary zip. I feel dumb. Thanks for helping me debug. +1

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of mvn.bat to see if it is blocked.